# Magento pre-order enterprise version

Tags: magento

I would like to give facility to purchase 'out of stock' products. I have enabled

System->Configuration-> Inventory->Display Out of Stock Products to 'Yes'
System->Configuration-> Inventory->Backorders set 'Allo Qty Below 0'

Cleared cache and rebuild indexing. Still I can't see 'Add to cart' button when taking out of stock product.
Front end product page shows message 'Availability: Out of stock'
Please advice.

Magento enterprise version 1.11.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Magento’s Back Order capabilities.

***Back Order – a business order yet to be fulfilled because stock is unavailable.***

To enable backorders, go to:

> Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog Tab -> Inventory ->
>   Product Stock Options -> Backorders = Allow Qty Below 0 and Notify
>   Customer

Now in Product -> Inventory tab

> Edit Product to Qty = 0

and

> Stock Availability = In Stock

When you add the particular product to cart, the product is added to cart and you will see the following message:*

This product is not available in the requested quantity. 1 of the items will be backordered.

You can order the product even if it is out of stock. The product will be delivered to you when it is in stock.